# Calculate IEnumerable<decimal> with decimal without using for-loop

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I was given a discount percentage as a decimal and I have `IEnumerable<decimal>` as a list of prices. I want to calculate discount price for each one in linq.

```
IEnumerable<decimal> prices = new IEnumerable<decimal>() { 100, 200, 300};
decimal discountPercentage = 20;
```

Shoot me some idea, I would love to try anything.

Comment: This is really simple linq. Just use `.Select`. we could give you the answer (and people probably will) but if so how will you learn?

Comment: @GiladGreen Indeed it is, I normally use .Select but somehow I totally forgot that we can just access it. Feeling embarress

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
IEnumerable<decimal> prices = new List<decimal>() { 100, 200, 300};
decimal discountPercentage = 20;
var discounted = prices.Select(x=>x-x/100*discountPercentage).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

If this is about discount price, you have to substract the discount from your price.

So a discount of `20%` from `100` would result into a discount price of  `80`.

```
IEnumerable<decimal> prices = new List<decimal>() { 100m, 200m, 300m };
decimal discountPercentage = 20;

IEnumerable<decimal> discPrices = prices.Select(x => x / 100 * (100 - discountPercentage));
// {80,160,240}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize `IEnumerable`. Use `List` instead

```
new List<decimal> { 100, 200, 300 }.
    Select(value => value * (100 - discountPercentage) / 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var discountPercentage = 20;

var discounted = prices.Select(p => p -= p * (discountPercentage / 100)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Select and ToList your result.

```
prices.Select(value => value - value * discountPercentage /100).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you cannot instantiate IEnumerable as it is an interface, not a concrete class. So, please use a List and add values to it.

A suggested answer,

```
IEnumerable<decimal> prices = new List<decimal>() { 100, 200, 300 };
decimal discountPercentage = 20;

// calculate prices after applying the discount via LINQ
prices = prices.Select(p => (100 - discountPercentage) / 100 * p);  

// displaying for testing purposes     
foreach (decimal price in prices)
{
    Console.WriteLine(price);
}
```

This will display the calculated discount prices like below,

80.0
160.0
240.0